# Selector in JQuery works without closing brackets

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know why does this selector work fine without closing brackets?

```
$("div[name=test1")
```

And gives the same result as this:

```
$("div[name=test1]")
```

HTML:

```
<div name="test1"> Content Test 1</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/w9awt3o3/)

Comment: Because the Sizzle selector engine is robust, and will figure out what you meant. If you have a space in the attribute value this probably wouldn't work. You really should close the brace though.

Comment: Kind of the same way that most browsers allow for non standard HTML/XHTML or weird CSS attributes, they are tolerant and try to behave politely. Which is the best policy when it comes to free-text, non compiled languages which may be written and executed on a large variety of platforms.

Comment: Don't know for sure but expect that Sizzle uses Event Based Parsing, which is not inherently tolerant of missing tokens, but can be written such that it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check [sizzle.js](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js) code on [github](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/). At Line 856 you have this treatment for attributes quotes on selectors:

```
// Make sure that attribute selectors are quoted
expr = expr.replace( rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" );
```

Which will in fact replace this `[name=test1` with this `[name='test1']`